# Jackson: Configuring an Entity for both Xml and JSON formats

Tags: java, xml, json, rest, jackson

I can have an Entity which supports JSON format with the help of `@JsonPropertyOrder`.
 XML support can be get by using `@XmlRootElement, @XmlAttribute, @XmlElement`.
How can I configure an entity which supports both XML and JSON formats?

Answer (score 2):

Jackson has a [module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations) that will allow you to use your JAXB (`@XMLRootElement` etc.) annotations to map to JSON as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just annotate the entity's properties with both annotations.

When you perform serialization, you'll choose an `ObjectMapper` or the corresponding `XmlMapper` (or whatever it is called) based on the type you want.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain more on the serialization part? Would there be `if-else` for mapper?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav I'm guessing you have some logic that decides if you want to generate XML or JSON. Based on that, use the proper mapper.

Comment: May be not. It is a new codebase so I may be wrong. As Controller is configured to produce both XML and JOSN. `@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})`.I assume Entity should be serialized in both formats without adding any `if-else` in place. Isn't it?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav You don't need to add the `if-else`, but whatever handles the `@Produces` will. I don't know enough about JAX RS to help you there.